# Reduce dict based on duplicate list values, regardless order of list

Tags: python

I have a **dict** in Python that looks like this:

```
{
    'key_1': ['3', '2', '4', '4', '5', '6'],
    'key_2': ['3', '4', '8', '7', '5', '1'],
    'key_3': ['7', '2', '8', '4', '2', '5'],
    'key_4': ['3', '2', '4', '4', '5', '6'],
    'key_5': ['8', '8', '4', '4', '4', '1'],
    'key_6': ['9', '3', '3', '3', '6', '1'],
    'key_7': ['4', '2', '3', '6', '4', '5']
}
```

I need to **reduce this down to only the unique lists**, regardless of the order in the list. For example, the above would be reduced to:

```
{
    'key_1': ['3', '2', '4', '4', '5', '6'],
    'key_2': ['3', '4', '8', '7', '5', '1'], 
    'key_3': ['7', '2', '8', '4', '2', '5'],
    'key_5': ['8', '8', '4', '4', '4', '1'],
    'key_6': ['9', '3', '3', '3', '6', '1']
}
```

Since **key_1**, **key_4**, and **key_7** are all considered duplicates in the original dict (key_1 and key_4 were the exact same, and key_7 was the same as key_1 and key_4 but in different order).

In other words, **if any list contains the same numbers, regardless of order, it should be considered a duplicate**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a record of any sequences you have already seen (sorting to make sure that order is the same across duplicates):

```
mydict = {
    'key_1': ['3', '2', '4', '4', '5', '6'],
    'key_2': ['3', '4', '8', '7', '5', '1'],
    'key_3': ['7', '2', '8', '4', '2', '5'],
    'key_4': ['3', '2', '4', '4', '5', '6'],
    'key_5': ['8', '8', '4', '4', '4', '1'],
    'key_6': ['9', '3', '3', '3', '6', '1'],
    'key_7': ['4', '2', '3', '6', '4', '5']
}

result = {}
seen = set()

for k, v in mydict.items():
    sorted_v = tuple(sorted(v))
    if sorted_v not in seen:
        result[k] = v
        seen.add(sorted_v)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) + [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset):

```
# this create a dictionary using as keys the list multiset (Counter)
uniques = {frozenset(Counter(values).items()): key for key, values in data.items()}

# reverse the dictionary and build a list from the multiset
result = {key: list(Counter(dict(values)).elements()) for values, key in uniques.items()}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'key_7': ['5', '6', '2', '4', '4', '3'], 'key_2': ['8', '5', '1', '4', '7', '3'], 'key_3': ['5', '8', '2', '2', '4', '7'], 'key_5': ['1', '8', '8', '4', '4', '4'], 'key_6': ['3', '3', '3', '1', '9', '6']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def reduce_dict(d):
    ret = {}
    sorts = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        s = sorted(v)
        if s not in sorts:
            ret[k] = v
            sorts.append(s)

    return ret
```

This will iterate over the dictionary, keeping a list of all the sorted values.

Note that this will only preserve in python>=3.6.

```
>>> reduce_dict(d)
{'key_1': ['3', '2', '4', '4', '5', '6'], 
 'key_2': ['3', '4', '8', '7', '5', '1'], 
 'key_3': ['7', '2', '8', '4', '2', '5'], 
 'key_5': ['8', '8', '4', '4', '4', '1'], 
 'key_6': ['9', '3', '3', '3', '6', '1']}
```

You can also attempt to take advantage of the fact that dictionaries must have unique keys:

```
def reduce_dict(d):
    rev = {tuple(sorted(v)): (v, k) for k, v in d.items()}
    return {k: v for _, (v, k) in rev.items()}
```

However, this is not guaranteed to produce the first double. Note that the lists must be cast to `tuples` because lists are unhashable.

Comment: I like your second way a lot. I wouldn't use it in real code because of readability issues, but the idea is really nice!